# Algorithm: Find single number in array

Tags: algorithm

This is a leetcode question I just saw. The solution someone gave is a bit hard to understand, I'm hoping someone can elaborate a bit:

**Given an array of integers, every element appears three times except for one, which appears exactly once. Find that single one.**

*Do this in linear time with no extra space.*

The solution someone gave:

```
public int singleNumber(int[] A) {
    int ones = 0, twos = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < A.length; i++){
        ones = (ones ^ A[i]) & ~twos;
        twos = (twos ^ A[i]) & ~ones;
    }
    return ones;
}
```

This seems like an awesome solution, but It's a bit hard to understand. Someone in the comments said this could be extended to any number of repeats.

Comment: If every element appears twice except for one once then you could just xor all the numbers. I suppose this is the adaptation for 3 times.

Comment: Using the array `[n, n, n]`, it can be see that the variables take on the values `n, 0`, `0, n`, and `0, 0`. Now just show that the order of the array does not matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose for each of the bits in an int, you have a counter. That counter can take the values 0, 1, or 2. For each 1 bit in an input number, you increment the corresponding counter, looping back to 0 when you would hit 3.

If a number appears 3 times in the array, the counters corresponding to its 1 bits will be incremented 3 times for that number, ultimately having no effect. The number that appears once will have its corresponding counters incremented once, so at the end, the counters will reflect only the 1 bits of the number that appears once.

This is basically a ternary version of the "XOR everything" solution you would use if the repeated numbers appeared 2 times instead of 3. We could go a little further with the ternary and use the base 3 digits of the input instead of the bits, but bits are easier to work with.

---

The `ones` and `twos` variables are used to maintain these counters. A 1 bit in the `ones` variable corresponds to a counter value of 1, and a 1 bit in the `twos` variable corresponds to a counter value of 2. A counter value of 0 corresponds to 0 bits in both `ones` and `twos`.

This:

```
ones = (ones ^ A[i]) & ~twos;
twos = (twos ^ A[i]) & ~ones;
```

is a counter update. Look at it on a bit-by-bit basis.

If a bit is set to 0 in `A[i]`, then these lines don't affect that bit in `ones` and `twos`.

If a bit is set to 1 in `A[i]`, then

- if that bit is set in `ones`, it's unset in `ones` (because of the `^ A[i]`) and set in `twos` (because of the `^ A[i]`, and then `& ~ones` doesn't unset it because we just unset the bit in `ones`).
- if that bit is set in `twos`, it remains unset in `ones` (because of the `& ~twos`) and gets unset in `twos` (because of the `^ A[i]`).
- if that bit was unset in both `ones` and `twos`, it gets set in `ones` (because of the `^ A[i]`) and remains unset in `twos` (because of the `& ~ones`).

At the end, `ones` has its bits set corresponding to the element of `A` that only appeared once, so we return `ones`.

Comment: thats a great way to look at it. Thanks for the explanation.